# QDBus interface watch - g_bus_watch_name

Tags: qt, interface, dbus, watch, qdbus

Does Qt expose a method to watch a DBus interface, similar with [`g_bus_watch_name`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-Watching-Bus-Names.html#g-bus-watch-name)? I want to know when an application is started or closed, watching its DBus interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`QDBusServiceWatcher`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdbusservicewatcher.html) class that can monitor the bus for service changes. From the docs-

> The QDBusServiceWatcher class allows the user to watch for a bus
>   service change.
>
> A QDBusServiceWatcher object can be used to notify the application
>   about an ownership change of a service name on the bus. It has three
>   watch modes:
>
> - Watching for service registration only.
> - Watching for service unregistration only.
> - Watching for any kind of service ownership change (the default mode).